# GCP VM FQDN Access using Browser

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have created a gcp vm and i ssh into the VM and try to execute the following command:
`hostname --fqdn` , it give me the following output:

```
VM-Name.us-central1.us.domain.net
```

I have application running on port 8080, i try to access the application using

```
VM-Name.us-central1.us.domain.net:8088
```

i am not able to access the same in the browser, it was earlier working for different project where i am trying to access in the similar manner.

Via IP i can access. Can someone please help ?

Comment: That DNS name is VPC local (meaning private) or is just the OS hostname. Unless you have created your own public DNS resource name pointing to the VM's public IP address, you have to use the public IP address to access the instance.

Comment: @JohnHanley For other VM i can access it through browser, our gcp can only be accessible through aVPN network

Comment: I do not understand your comment. Edit your question with new details. How you access other cloud providers (aws, azure, etc) may or may not apply to how you access Google Cloud resources. If you are using a VPN then include that detail as that changes everything. Include how DNS forwarding is setup.